# How to remove distance between two bars in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, axis

I am trying to plot bar graphs in matplotlib. I have set frequency of X-axis manually in matplotlib by using plt.xticks. But i can not remove the distance between two bars (first and second). What should i do to remove the distance between two horizontal bars?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 15, 20, 25])
y = np.array([3500, 4239, 5239, 6239])

plt.bar(x, y, width = 2.5, edgecolor='black', color=['olive', 'seagreen', 'green', 'darkgreen'] )

plt.xticks([0, 15, 20, 25])

plt.legend()
plt.grid(color = 'slategrey', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.15)

plt.show()
```

As a newbie what should I do?

[image: Here is the graph picture]

Comment: Which two bars do you mean?

Comment: the first bar at 0 value and the second bar at 15 value.

Comment: Don't! They are further apart than the other ones, because their x-difference is larger. It's really bad practice to hide that fact.

Comment: I have added the values in both x and y axis. I am not hiding any value. I just want to scale the graph and make it look compact

Comment: You're cheating the ye; distances, gaps, are easier spotted than the actual numbers. In the current graph, people will remember the graph. If you put the first two bars next to each other, people will remember a nice sequential set of bars, which it isn't.

Comment: I am adding all the values with the graph. I just cant leave a big space in the middle of two bars. Thanks for replying though but I needed the help. So please cooperate if you can. And again, I am not cheating at all. I am adding value to the graph and will also add analysis of the graph in my assignment.

Comment: "I just cant leave a big space in the middle of two bars. ": of course you can: those are the actual values. That's how the world is. You wouldn't suddenly show the distance New-York to London to be the same as London to Paris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick by-hand solution, you could use your x-values just as labels and equidistant ones for the plotting:

```
x = np.array([0, 15, 20, 25])
y = np.array([3500, 4239, 5239, 6239])

x_new = np.arange(len(x))

plt.bar(x_new, y, width = 0.5, edgecolor='black', color=['olive', 'seagreen', 'green', 'darkgreen'] )

plt.xticks(x_new, labels =x)

plt.legend()
plt.grid(color = 'slategrey', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.15)

plt.show()
```